# Lipschitz continuity of bounded and convex functions on an open convex subset of a normed space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider a bounded convex function $f$ defined on an open convex subset of a normed space. Show that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Why can't we consider as a counterexample the following convex function which is bounded on its domain:

$$f(x) = -\sqrt x, x \in (0, 1)$$

Comment: That _is_ a counterexample.

Comment: That's what I figured. Although it's not mentioned in the errata of the book I'm working through. Thanks for clarifying.